# SQL Server installation issues

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to install SQL Server on my Windows 10 PC. I am a beginner in SQL Server. Every time I install, I get a failed installation for the Database Engine Services. I don't know what the the issue is.

I have tried installing it multiple times. Repairing the software also does not work.

Here is the error that I found in the Summery Log File. Please help:

> The SQL Server feature 'SQL_Engine_Core_Inst' is not in a supported state for repair, as it was never successfully configured. Only features from successful installations can be repaired. To continue, remove the specified SQL Server feature.
>
> Error help link:
> https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=15.0.2000.5&EvtType=0x2841E06E%401204%402&EvtType=0x2841E06E%401204%402

Comment: You can use docker to run a MSSQL container on your PC.

Comment: Have you tried full uninstalling it first? You might need to manually remove bits from the registry. Perhaps try https://sqlgeekspro.com/uninstall-sql/. Are you definitely running Windows 10 and not Windows 11?

Comment: Yes for sure ! And I have tried unintalling multiple times .Including removing all the data from program files registry and app data files.Nothing works

Comment: Which edition of SQL Server 2019 are you trying to install? Version 15.0.2000.5 is the RTM release from November 04, 2019... have you tried downloading a current installer?

Comment: I am installing a current installer from official microsoft website by dowloading the offline installation media